# How to update QTableWidgetItems when a new delegate is chosen?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14, qtablewidgetitem

I've created a QTableWidget which I change the delegate based upon an button.  I've been able to get the different delegates set up with the QTableWidget, but changing the delegates doesn't seem to automatically update the QTableWidgetItems.  When I go into a user edit of the QTableWidget item through the actual UI, the item is correctly updated to the correct delegate.

Here is an example of the code I'm using to update the delegate:

```
//here is the item delegate I used
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <limits>

class IntDelegate : public QItemDelegate {
    int m_min;
    int m_max;
public:
    explicit IntDelegate(int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
                         int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
                         QObject *parent = nullptr) : QItemDelegate(
            parent), m_min(min), m_max(max) {
    }

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        auto spinbox = new QSpinBox(parent);
        spinbox->setMinimum(m_min);
        spinbox->setMaximum(m_max);
        return spinbox;
    }

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                       const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        int value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toInt();
        auto *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox *>(editor);
        spinBox->setValue(value);
    }

    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                      const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        auto *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox *>(editor);
        spinBox->interpretText();
        int value = spinBox->value();

        model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
    }

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
                              const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    }
};
```

```
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <limits>

class DoubleDelegate : public QItemDelegate {
double m_min;
double m_max;
public:
explicit DoubleDelegate(double min = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
                        double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
                        QObject *parent = nullptr) : QItemDelegate(
        parent), m_min(min), m_max(max) {
}

QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                      const QModelIndex &index) const override {
    auto spinbox = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);
    spinbox->setMinimum(m_min);
    spinbox->setMaximum(m_max);
    spinbox->setDecimals(323);

    return spinbox;
}

void setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const override {
    double value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toDouble();
    auto *spinBox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox *>(editor);
    spinBox->setValue(value);
}

void
setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
             const QModelIndex &index) const override {
    auto *spinBox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox *>(editor);
    spinBox->interpretText();
    double value = spinBox->value();

    model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}

void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
                          const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const override {
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}

};
```

```
 #include <QTableWidget> // table matrix box
 #include <QLabel>
 #include <QVBoxLayout>
 #include <QGridLayout>
 #include <QFileDialog>
 #include "intdelegate.h"
 #include "doubledelegate.h"
 #include <QComboBox> // selection of QT type
 #include <limits>


 #define CV_8U 0
 #define CV_8S 1
 #define CV_16U 2
 #define CV_16S 3
 #define CV_32S 4
 #define CV_32F 5
 #define CV_64F 6

// inside area where widget is created
class MatrixBoxWidget : public QWidget {
     Q_OBJECT

     QTableWidget *m_matrix_table;
     QComboBox *m_cv_types_combobox;
public:
 explicit MatrixBoxWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr){
    m_cv_types_combobox = new QComboBox(this);

    m_cv_types_combobox->addItem("uint8", QVariant::fromValue(CV_8U));
    m_cv_types_combobox->addItem("int8", QVariant::fromValue(CV_8S));
    m_cv_types_combobox->addItem("uint16", QVariant::fromValue(CV_16U));
    m_cv_types_combobox->addItem("int16", QVariant::fromValue(CV_16S));
    m_cv_types_combobox->addItem("int32", QVariant::fromValue(CV_32S));
    m_cv_types_combobox->addItem("float", QVariant::fromValue(CV_32F));
    m_cv_types_combobox->addItem("double", QVariant::fromValue(CV_64F));


    connect(m_cv_types_combobox,
        qOverload<int>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this,
        &MatrixBoxWidget::validateDisplayType);

    QTableWidget *m_matrix_table = new QTableWidget(this);
    auto delegate = new IntDelegate();
    m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
    m_matrix_table->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
    m_matrix_table->item(0, 0)->setData(Qt::EditRole, 12723);
    m_matrix_table->setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem());
    m_matrix_table->item(0, 1)->setData(Qt::EditRole, 12723);
    m_matrix_table->setItem(1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
    m_matrix_table->item(1, 0)->setData(Qt::EditRole, 12723);
    m_matrix_table->setItem(1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem());
    m_matrix_table->item(1, 1)->setData(Qt::EditRole, 12723);

    auto type_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    auto type_label = new QLabel("type", this);
    type_layout->addWidget(type_label);
    type_layout->addWidget(m_cv_types_combobox);

    auto layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    layout->addLayout(type_layout, 0, 2);
    layout->addWidget(m_matrix_table, 1, 0, 3, 3);

}
void validateDisplayType(int index) {
    QVariant current_data = m_cv_types_combobox->currentData();
    auto cv_type = current_data.value<int>();
    QItemDelegate *delegate;
    switch (cv_type) {
        case CV_8U:
            delegate = new IntDelegate(std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::min(),
                                       std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max());
            m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
            break;
        case CV_8S:
            delegate = new IntDelegate(std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min(),
                                       std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max());
            m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
            break;
        case CV_16U:
            delegate = new IntDelegate(std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::min(),
                                       std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max());
            m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
            break;
        case CV_16S:
            delegate = new IntDelegate(std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::min(),
                                       std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max());
            m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
            break;
        case CV_32S:
            delegate = new IntDelegate(std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min(),
                                       std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max());
            m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
            break;
        case CV_32F:
            delegate = new DoubleDelegate(-std::numeric_limits<float>::max(),
                                          std::numeric_limits<float>::max());
            m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
            break;
        case CV_64F:
            delegate = new DoubleDelegate(-std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
                                          std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
            m_matrix_table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
            break;
        default:
            assert((false, "unknown type format"));
            break;
    }
};
```

For example, one delegate is a uint16_t delegate, I set the value of the item to 1024.  When I swap delegates I want the display to change the value displayed accordingly.  When I go to edit an item, this has perfect behavior, and the delegate value becomes 255, and similarly, if I use a delegate that uses Doubles for display, then switch to integers, I go from 2.234 to 2. example of this in action, same number used for all, but I edit when the delegate changes and the correct range is clamped for it (going from uint16 to uint8):

[image]

How do I force this behavior programmically when I switch the delegate instead of having to manually click on the display? I've tried updating the viewport but I don't think its doing what I think it does:

```
m_matrix_table->viewport()->update();
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: you say it does not work, that's called an error, it's not a syntax error but an error.

Comment: only the delegate provides

Comment: I also think that with the reputation you have, you know that an MCVE does not necessarily refer to its project, but rather a code that can be a mini-project.

Comment: Well, I will try to reproduce your problem :) although I do not know where it is.

Comment: @eyllanesc So are you saying that my assumption that changing the delegate doesn't update the QTableWidgetItems display is wrong?

Comment: I just had a look into source code at woboq.org: [`QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView15setItemDelegateEP21QAbstractItemDelegate) does already a `viewport()->update();`. (If I didn't overlook something the derived classes don't overload this.)

Comment: @eyllanesc I've provided more code.